# How authenticated users can choose favorite products and show them in their profile?

Tags: 7, users

in my drupal project, I want to have many products specification. I want authenticated users can choose their favorite product and they can set price for favorite product. these favorite products can show in their user's profile. and in any product page, all users can see all of the prices that set by authenticated users.

In Drupal 7 which approach / technique should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really seems like a perfect fit for the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. Excerpt from its project page (bold markup added here):

> ... Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.
>
> **Flags may be** per-user, meaning that each user can mark an item individually, or **global, meaning that the item is either marked or it is not marked, and any user who changes that changes it for everyone.**
>
> In this way, additional flags (similar to published and sticky) can be put on nodes, or other items, and dealt with by the system however the administration likes.

If you're not familiar with the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, checkout the [set of 8 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-flag-with-nodeone) about the flag module.

Refer to Flag's [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag) for (way) more details.

And to show this in their user's profile, could be implemented via an appropriate view (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)), in the format of a block display, whereas you adapt the block visibility settings to only show such block for an URL that corresponds with the user's profile.

Comment: Merci (oeps: thank you) for the accept! May I say "next question"?

Comment: yeah, i forgot it. sorry. 
Another question. I don't know how authenticated users can set their favorite price on any product? one product has many prices. how can I do it? for example, one product can has a certain price in any user's profile.
A user sets product's price 200$ and B user sets it 150 $.

Comment: Hm, that's indeed a **NEW** question, which I recommend you to post as a new (separated) question. Adding it here via an extra comment here is not really compliant to the rules of this site. But to help you prepare for such new question, make sure it is clear what you actually want. So therefor first this extra comment from me: I'd think a "user" has to "agree" with the "price" that the website owner has decided to ask as "a" price for a product. So how can it be allowed in your case that "user A" has price 1, and "user B" has price 2?

Comment: I ask NEW question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193317/how-users-can-set-price-for-products

Comment: OK, that new question now seems "clear" to me. Though I don't know an answer to it. But I do wonder why you tagged it with "flag". If you are using "drupal commerce" (or kickstart), then I suggest you change the tags to those tags. Probably also add the "7" tag to it. Also, if you are not using commerce or kickstart, then add that also to your question (to avoid confusion, and hence invalid answers). I'd be interested to see any answer to make it work like you are asking for!

Comment: Merc. I tagged with drupal commerce. your help was useful for my first question. Thank you.