# How can users set their own price for their products?

Tags: 7, commerce

This question is a followup question to [my prior question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-authenticated-users-can-choose-favorite-products-and-show-them-in-their-prof) ...

Consider authenticated users of site are "STOREs". Any store (= user) should be able to set the product's price in their profile. So that product A sells at 200$ for Store B and sells at 150$ for Store C. How can I do it? I want Stores can set their price in their profile.

Comment: This question is likely to get closed because it does not fit the community rules around asking specific questions that contain some semblance of what you have attempted. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions With that out of the way, have you looked at https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist ?

Comment: @Hamed in case you want to try to address the possible reason why this question may be put on hold (cfr prior comment), I suggest you briefly explain what you already have setup (maybe link to your prior question?), and what the missing piece of your puzzle is.

Comment: @joshmiller Commerce pricelist isn't useful. because is not my mean. please see my prior question.
 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-authenticated-users-can-choose-favorite-products-and-show-them-in-their-prof

Comment: @pierre You are a Helpful man. I respect to you. ;)

Comment: @Hamed in that case you will need to use a field collection https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection on the user entity (with a product reference and price field) and then use Pricing Rules https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-pricing-rules-screencasts to set the price to the specified field to change the price. To be useful you would probably need some form of context to know which user to load and which price to use.

Comment: Thank you for taking my advice (in my prior comment). I just slightly edited your question, trying to further improve it a bit. Please double check my edit, and further correct/refine where appropriate. E.g. by adding "I"m using Drupal Commerce" (if that's the case of course). PS: I'm just trying to get a new user on this site to get going with this site ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module (as I suggested in my answer to your prior question to "[How authenticated users can choose favorite products and show them in their profile?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-authenticated-users-can-choose-favorite-products-and-show-them-in-their-prof)", you could implement an extra (price) field when you define a flag. Such field can then be used to store the Product's price.

So if a user (= Store) then flags a product (to indicated "This store sells this product"), such user could use the extra field to actually indicate the price for that store.

Refer to the community documentation about [Attaching fields to flags](https://www.drupal.org/node/917576) for more details about this.

Comment: Woowww... Great... You are GENIUS... Thank you Pierre

Comment: Merci (oeps: thank you) for the accept (and the kudos)! Keep me informed (eg via some extra comment around here) if you ever have a "next question", ok? FYI: now that you know the kind of things you can do with the Flag module, you might want to look at how the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module works great for all sorts of combinations (integrations) of both modules. To get a heads up of what I mean, have a look at [these questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a39516%20%5brules%5d) ...